# Why does windbg search different paths for dump and exe file?

Tags: c++, windbg

When I open a dump file in WinDbg, it looks for pdb files in `c:\code\appV1` folder

When I open the exe file directly in WinDbg, it looks for the pdb files in `c:\code\appV2` folder.

This is driving me crazy because in both cases, windbg is debugging the same exe which is at c:\MyApp\app.exe

The `c:code\appV1` make sense to search in, this is path where pdb files were generated by the exe but why does it search in `c:\code\appV2` which has no connection whatsoever with the dump file or the exe?

Comment: This can't be answered without knowing what you set as `.sympath` and without knowing where the DLL was loaded from. Perhaps the DLL is registered at that location? When debugging, it's necessary to be precise and have a look at details. You're probably missing a small detail and you provide even less detail in your question for us to solve it.

Comment: @ThomasWeller understandable but I don't set anything with `.sympath`. The `.reload` debug output doesn't even tell me it searches either path and I have to dig into use process monitor and was surprised where it was looking for in each case. Process monitor output is the only thing I have to show the results and that's visual window.

Comment: @zar You may use !sym noisy to help debug symbol loading issues, including searched paths.

Comment: @Dono I did use that but in some sessions, it doesn't show the exact paths it searches. I think such inconsistent are what makes the tool a little harder to use but this is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: @zar WinDbg Please include all relevant details in your question. That includes the commands used and the output produced. Indicate what you expect and why you think the output is incorrect. Otherwise your question not answerable. You can start with including the output of .sympath. Then enable !sym noisy. Then show the output of a failed symbol search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did extensive digging into this, created a demo project and simulated crash and tried various combinations. The answer is that dump file seems to have an overriding effect on the executable when it comes to default search paths (pdb).

Here is how you can reproduce this scenario:

1. Create project called App1 at say c:\code\App1 and build it.
2. Copy the above project and rename the main folder as App1Clone and build it, say in c:\code\App1Clone

Now first copy App1 to say c:\test folder and run it. It will crash and create dump file.

Now copy the App1 from App1Clone folder to c:\test folder and run it. It will crash and create dump file.

Now both dump files are linked to c:\test\app1.exe but if the wrong app1.exe was present (=search paths didn't match) it will apparently pick the paths supposedly stored in the dump file. I don't know if dump files even store this path but this appears to be the case based on my experimentation.